How to override queryset for newly added fieldset in Django Admin Panel
I have added "permissions" fieldset in my User model on Admin Panel, but when I try to add a User it takes a lot of queries due to permissions (500) in my case, I am not able to optimize the code because get_queryset is not executing while adding an object.
I want to know how can I fetch all related permissions in add user form, so it should fetch all select related permissions to optimize the admin panel interface.

Please mention code from your User class

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
